# Changing function to check for username || password

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code that checks for both the username and password but I would like to change it so that it checks to see if the username or password is valid.

I was thinking of making two different functions `checkUsername` and `checkPassword` as functions and have two call backs for each input.

I just would like to know if I am on the right track or if my controller and model can be altered how they are?

**Model:**

```
    function check_login($username,$password) {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, password FROM users WHERE email = ? and password = ?", array($username, md5($password))); // Result

        return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? $query->row() : FALSE;

    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function _checkUsernamePassword() {
        // adding the _ makes the function 'private' so it can't be called from the URI.

            extract($_POST); // Gets data from form and creates vars

            $user = $this->login_model->check_login($username,$password);

            if(! $user){ // != If username or password are not correct
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error',TRUE); //does not add the non valid login to the session
                $this->form_validation->set_message('_checkUsernamePassword', 'Sorry %s is not correct.');
                return FALSE;

            } else {
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$user->id);
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_name',$user->first_name);
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_email',$user->email);
                return TRUE;

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you ever have a scenario where you want to determine if a user name exists on its own? If not, I see no reason to add the extra functions. It's generally considered a bad practice to let the client know that a username was valid if an invalid password was submitted. It lets a malicious person know that they've solved 50% of the puzzle, freeing them to crack the password only. Further, I can't imagine a scenario where you'd want to check if a password exists on its own.

One thing I would note from your code is that `md5` has been broken and [`sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) is really a better option for storing passwords these days. Otherwise, without poring over the code looking for tiny improvements I'd say that you've used prepared statements with your inputs and everything else looks okay, so you're probably fine.

Comment: Dont get me started on the MD5,  hence why I am redoing the code.  You have just given me a valid point :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option: change the model, so you can specify whether to check for one or both.

```
function check_login($username,$password, $match_both = true) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, password FROM users WHERE email = ? " . ($match_both ? 'AND' : 'OR') . " password = ?", array($username, md5($password))); // Result

    return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? $query->row() : FALSE;

}
```

Comment: Nope, it's just a regular old variable. You can call `login_model->check_login($user, $pass, TF)` where TF is either `true` or `false`, to change how the function operates - scroll right and read the query fully

Answer (score 0):

Yes better to check for user name first then go for passwrd check.
that way it will be more secure.

and use mysql_real_escape_string() to esacape special characters in the inputted username and password. else theere will be a way for sql injection.

Comment: OP is clearly using prepared statements here, so `mysql_escape_string` would be a step backwards.